# OperationalError: 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to snowflake using my login credentials. I'm using the following code:

```
snowflake.connector.connect(
    user="<my_user_name>",
    password="<my_password>",
    account="<my_account_name_with_region_and_cloud>"
    )
```

When I try to run the above code, I'm getting the following error:

OperationalError: 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://hm53485.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=fcfdd77a-11ff-4956-9ed8-bcc332c5989a&databaseName=S3_DB&schemaName=PUBLIC&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH&request_guid=b9fdb5c9-81cb-4ecb-8d20-abef44249bbf

I'm sure that all my packages are up to date. I'm using python 3.6.4 and the latest snowflake_connector_python.

I'm currently on *us-east-2* location in aws.

Can someone please help me out on this????

Comment: You should select an answer if one helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Just Give your account name in the account .We dont need the region and full URL.
Please check below .

----------------------------------------------------------------------
import snowflake.connector


PASSWORD = '*******'
USER = '<USERNAME>'
ACCOUNT = 'SFCSUPPORT'
WAREHOUSE = '<WHNAME>'
DATABASE = '<DBNAME>'
SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'

print("Connecting...")
# -- (> ------------------- SECTION=connect_to_snowflake --------------------
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
  user=USER,
  password=PASSWORD,
  account=ACCOUNT,
  warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
  database=DATABASE,
  schema=SCHEMA
)


con.cursor().execute("USE WAREHOUSE " + WAREHOUSE)
con.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE " + DATABASE)
#con.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA INFORMATION_SCHEMA")


try:
    result = con.cursor().execute("Select * from <TABLE>")
    result_list = result.fetchall()
    print(result_list)

finally:
    con.cursor().close()
con.cursor().close()
```

Comment: We actually need region and cloud or I was getting error. I had to put `FCXXXX.us-east-2.aws`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using sqlalchemy, which you can install via pip:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html

Here's what I have at the beginning of my notebook:

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

url = URL(
    account = 'xxxxxxxx.east-us-2.azure',
    user = 'xxxxxxxx',
    password = 'xxxxxxxx',
    database = 'xxxxxxxx',
    schema = 'xxxxxxxx',
    warehouse = 'xxxxxxxx',
    role='xxxxxxxx'
)

engine = create_engine(url)
connection = engine.connect()

query = '''
    select 1 AS VAL;
'''

df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)

df
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error. Tried few things like making sure the account name is correct as per https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html. The account name depends on the region in which your snowflake account is located. Note that some of the cloud regions need a cloud provider name at  the end and some do it.

But it didn't help fix the issue I was facing. For me, it turned out to be a proxy issue. I was trying to connect from a corporate network with a proxy and it was blocking the connection to Snowflake. Whitelisting the snowflake URL in proxy fixed the issue for me.